# Windows batchfile asking for admin rights and download a file in curl fails

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch file like this

```
@echo off

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:checkPrivileges
NET FILE 1>NUL 2>NUL
if '%errorlevel%' == '0' (goto gotPrivileges) else (goto getPrivileges)
:getPrivileges
echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
echo For Each strArg in WScript.Arguments >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
echo If strArg = WScript.Arguments.Item^(0^) Then d = Left^(strArg, InStrRev^(strArg,"\"^) - 1^) >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
echo args = args ^& " " ^& strArg  >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
echo Next >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
echo UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", ^("/c start /D """ ^& d ^& """ /B" ^& args ^& " ^& exit"^), , "runas", 4 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
cscript "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" ""%~s0"" %*
del /q "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
exit /b
:gotPrivileges
:: Your code here

echo "Downloading old version of OrthoSelect..."

curl -o ./6.7.5.zip "https://github.com/ruellm/OrthoSelect_6.7.5/archive/refs/tags/6.7.5.zip"

pause
```

It ask for an admin permission and executes curl to download the file, but unfortunately, even if the admin rights is given, the zip file downloaded is only 1Kb, the entire zip file is not downloaded properly,
The console window do not show error as well.

Anyone can help whats wrong?

Comment: Open that file with a text editor and it will be immediately obvious what's wrong and what flag you need to add.

Comment: @SomethingDark I appreciate you replying, but can you point me whats wrong? I cant seem to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Links to files on Github are not direct links, so if you try to simply `curl` the file, you'll end up only downloading the redirect page instead. If you use a text editor to open the file that you've downloaded, you'll see

```
<html><body>You are being <a href="https://codeload.github.com/ruellm/OrthoSelect_6.7.5/zip/refs/tags/6.7.5">redirected</a>.</body></html>
```

This should tell you that you need to use the `-L` flag to follow redirects:
`curl -L "https://github.com/ruellm/OrthoSelect_6.7.5/archive/refs/tags/6.7.5.zip" -o 6.7.5.zip`